# Is there a way to ignore tests in crate nested in workpace?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a crate nested in a workspace as a git subtree folder, and I don't want to run any tests on that nested crate whenever I run `cargo test` in the workspace. Is there a way to tell it to ignore this particular crate?

Comment: There's the `--exclude <crate>` command-line flag. Are you looking for a way to persist that in a configuration file?

Comment: @PitaJ, that's workable, but I'd prefer to be able to do this in a configuration file.

Comment: Would a [cargo alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#alias) work for you?

Comment: Ooo, cargo alias is good to know about!

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a list of `default-members` in your workspace's `Cargo.toml`. Doing so will not use unlisted packages for normal cargo commands unless specified by `-p excluded_pkg`.

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html) of `cargo test`:

> #### Package Selection
>
> If the manifest is the root of a workspace then the workspaces default members are selected...

Here's an example:

```ini
[workspace]
resolver = "2"
members = [
    "included_pkg_a",
    "included_pkg_b",
    "excluded_pkg",
]
default-members = [
    "included_pkg_a",
    "included_pkg_b",
]
```